# Newtonsoft Json deserialization error

Tags: c#, json

This is a really weird error happened. I have these objects:

```
public class Mobile_SettingModels
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public SettingViewModels Setting { get; set; }
}

public class SettingViewModels
{
    public string CompanyToken { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int MarkRedAfter { get; set; }
}
```

I got this response from Json response:

```
{
    "Token":"DEJkEKQpAUR3UvUc5ZFoYAO4vt3Cq4ErZOc/KeERRu0N+Pc/gzAQ538tMGALuxnKtangfEv81bZ7D3P3WdeUoE76KMveGqcP7JepYIL3EBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz==",
    "Setting":
        {
            "CompanyToken":"xxxxxxxx",
            "ApiKey":"AIzaSyAZ6bZ02BAd_zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
            "Password":null,
            "MarkRedAfter":30
        }
}
```

This is how I get this response.

```
var values = new NameValueCollection() {
    { "token", myToken }
};

var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(uploadUrl, values));
var setting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mobile_SettingModels>(result);
```

Whenever I deserialize it, the setting.Token value is correct, but the setting.Setting is a mess.

What possibly went wrong here?

---

### Update

So when I debug it, apparently the `var setting` has:

1. Setting
2. Token
3. << Setting >>k__BackingField
4. << Token >>k__BackingField

This is super weird because I do not have any `Serializable` attribute on my object. Also I am sure the response I got does not have `Serializable` attribute, because otherwise it will have k_BackingField in the result.

Also the setting.Setting is considered as `Mobile_SettingModels` object not `SettingViewModels`. So the setting.Setting has `Token` and `Setting` again?

My NewtonsoftJson version is 10.0.3

What is happening?

---

### Update

So actually the problem is with the **Xamarin Live Device Player Debugging**. I use live player debugging in my Xiao Mi Redmi A4. It works fine if the Json object is only 1 layer. If there is nested objects it will fail. I use the emulator debugging and everything works as expected. I am sure it is a bug.

Unless someone here can tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Can you construct a test version and populate the object then serialise it to JSON?  Maybe looking at the difference will assist you.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, Settings are deserialized correctly from the JSON you specified. Are you sure that `result` is exactly the same JSON as you pasted in your question?

Comment: Can you debug it and show us what exactly is in var result?

Comment: var setting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mobile_SettingModels>>(result);     //try this it looks like you have lists within that object..

Comment: Yes that result is what i get from `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(uploadUrl, values));`. That is what I see from the debugging.

Comment: @AlvinStefanus have you tried my code. how did it go!!

Comment: I think @AlvinStefanus is correct, this definitely seems like a bug.  I have exactly the same problem.  When viewing in the Live player, top level deserialization works fine, but child objects are NOT deserialized into the proper classes.  When you view the same code in the emulator, the problem vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

For backing field issue you have to change your server side code..provide backing field for each property ..you are serializing at server end

I think I got your issue

```
<< Setting >>k__BackingField
<< Token >>k__BackingField
```

, issue because you declared automatic property in your service class i.e. in your webservice

```
public Setting {get;set;}
public Token {get;set;}
```

to resolve it you can create backing value for it as below

```
private Setting _setting;
public Setting {get {return _setting;}set {_setting= value;}
private Token _token;
public Token {get {return _token;}set {_token= value;}
```

I faced same issue when I started working with WebAPI in my application, when I provided backing fields then it worked for me.

---

tried your code at my end and it seems working

```
 string json = "{" +
                         "'Token':'DEJkEKQpAUR3UvUc5ZFoYAO4vt3Cq4ErZOc/KeERRu'," +
        "'Setting':" +
        "{" +
            "'CompanyToken':'xxxxxxxx'," +
            "'ApiKey':'AIzaSyAZ6bZ02BAd_zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'," +
            "'Password':null," +
            "'MarkRedAfter':30" +
        "}" +
       "}";

 var setting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mobile_SettingModels>(json);
```

---

Please check you are trying something like this , below is example code call made to webAPI created by asp.net WebAPI framework.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())  
{  
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("url");  
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();  
  using (HttpContent content = response.Content)  
  {  
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mobile_SettingModels>(responseBody);  

  }
}
```

Comment: I think everything is working fine, because the response result I got is correct. The problem is with the deserialization. I am really confused here

Comment: @AlvinStefanus - for backing field issue you have to change your server side code..provide backing field for each property ..you are serializing at server end..

Comment: I have checked the server and there is no serialization attribute used in there. I have tried to use you test case above. I know where the problem is now. The problem is within the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(). The result of it produces k_backingfield also the `setting.Setting` reference again to itself. I dont know how is this happened. So the debbuging said the setting.Token is type string, but the setting.Setting is type `Mobile_SettingModel` it should be `SettingViewModels`.